# Проблема со SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, java

Привет!

Мне надоело использовать всякие костыли типа [`ActionBar-PullToRefresh`](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh), поэтому я переключился на наконец-то найденный [`android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html).

На Хабре сразу же нашёл [пример реализации](http://habrahabr.ru/post/218365/) и загрузил демо-APK для проверки. Да, цветные *полосы* [идут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZhiv.jpg), значит всё ок. Подключил в своё приложение `android.support.v4 21.0` и добавил `SwipeRefreshLayout`, однако что бы я не делал, каждый раз у меня появляется этот [кружок](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhxnz.jpg). Я всё думал, что гугл просто обновил эти полосы на кружок в какой-то новой версии support library (ведь в демо с Хабра использовалась либа версии 19.1, а у меня подключена версия 21.0), но поглазев на [историю изменений](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions), никакой смены дизайна у `SwipeRefreshLayout` я не увидел.

Вопрос: как изменить кружок на полосы?

Comment: О-па, для HashCode клиент пишете? Это плюс!

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, я его уже второй год написать пытаюсь -_-.

То комп сломается, то флешка с бэкапом проекта потеряется, позор, короче.

Сейчас наконец-то на Git перешёл, процесс разработки ускорился. Скорее всего, где-то летом уже доделаю. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Кружочек" появился вместе с Material Design в 21 версии. Если хотите использовать `SwipeRefreshLayout` с цветными линиями как в Kit Kat, то надо использовать старую версию Support Library.